# Infer generics with interface - java

Tags: java, generics

i have the following interface:

```
public interface Evaluator<T> {
    T evaluate(Collection<Extractable> sample);
 }
```

And a class implementing that interface:

```
public class PrecisionEvaluator implements Evaluator<Map<Triple<Short, Integer, String>, AttributePrecisionBean>> {

@Override
public Map<Triple<Short, Integer, String>, AttributePrecisionBean> evaluate(Collection<Extractable> sample){
    ...
```

}

so the usage of the above would be:

```
Evaluator<Map<Triple<Short, Integer, String>, AttributePrecisionBean>> eval = new PrecisionEvaluator();
```

Is there a way to to make the interface Evaluator implicitly return the generic type defined in the class implementing it? so that the usage would simply be:

```
Evaluator eval = new PrecisionEvaluator();
```

Or is there a cleaner way to go about it?

Comment: I think the real problem you are having is that you didn't give `Map<Triple<Short, Integer, String>, AttributePrecisionBean>` it's own name and therefore its own class.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, an object of type `Evaluator` will be a raw type, unless you specify the generic type. What you can do since Java 7 is the type inference for generic instance creation (though it probably won't help in this case):

```
Evaluator<Map<Triple<Short, Integer, String>, AttributePrecisionBean>> eval
    = new Evaluator<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there is a way to do it : learn Scala, its syntax is far simpler than Java's, thanks to, among other reasons, the compiler type inference.

More seriously, you cannot do better with Java, if you use `Evaluator` alone it is going to be compiled as `Evaluator<Object>`, which will not allow you to have type safety and polymorphism. All you could do here is creating a class `class CustomTriple extends Triple<Short,Integer,String>>`  to have something shorter.